# Transmission-daemon to port-forward

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, bittorrent, p2p, transmission

I have been using the Transmission BitTorrent GTK client to port-forward on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I would just go to the preferences and set specific port for it to open, and stop it from randomising the port on start up. It all worked well, but every time I reboot, i have to manually open it up again.

I was just wondering if anyone knew a way to do the same thing with transmission-daemon, so i can run it on startup. I have had a look at the file "/root/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json", and changed a few things for it to look like this:

```
{
"alt-speed-down": 50, 
"alt-speed-enabled": false, 
"alt-speed-time-begin": 540, 
"alt-speed-time-day": 127, 
"alt-speed-time-enabled": false, 
"alt-speed-time-end": 1020, 
"alt-speed-up": 50, 
"bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0", 
"bind-address-ipv6": "::", 
"blocklist-enabled": false, 
"blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist", 
"cache-size-mb": 4, 
"dht-enabled": true, 
"download-dir": "/root/Downloads", 
"download-queue-enabled": true, 
"download-queue-size": 5, 
"encryption": 1, 
"idle-seeding-limit": 30, 
"idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false, 
"incomplete-dir": "/root/Downloads", 
"incomplete-dir-enabled": false, 
"lpd-enabled": false, 
"message-level": 2, 
"peer-congestion-algorithm": "", 
"peer-limit-global": 240, 
"peer-limit-per-torrent": 60, 
"peer-port": 8888, 
"peer-port-random-high": 8888, 
"peer-port-random-low": 8888, 
"peer-port-random-on-start": false, 
"peer-socket-tos": "default", 
"pex-enabled": true, 
"port-forwarding-enabled": true, 
"preallocation": 1, 
"prefetch-enabled": 1, 
"queue-stalled-enabled": true, 
"queue-stalled-minutes": 30, 
"ratio-limit": 2, 
"ratio-limit-enabled": false, 
"rename-partial-files": true, 
"rpc-authentication-required": false, 
"rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0", 
"rpc-enabled": true, 
"rpc-password": "{55d4d000989c62965af36b6e6638320ae1c06c4f/JRl7s8X", 
"rpc-port": 9091, 
"rpc-url": "/transmission/", 
"rpc-username": "", 
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1", 
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true, 
"scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true, 
"script-torrent-done-enabled": false, 
"script-torrent-done-filename": "", 
"seed-queue-enabled": false, 
"seed-queue-size": 10, 
"speed-limit-down": 100, 
"speed-limit-down-enabled": false, 
"speed-limit-up": 100, 
"speed-limit-up-enabled": false, 
"start-added-torrents": true, 
"trash-original-torrent-files": false, 
"umask": 18, 
"upload-slots-per-torrent": 14, 
"utp-enabled": true, 
"watch-dir": ".config/transmission-daemon/settings.json", 
"watch-dir-enabled": true
}
```

I was also wondering if it was possible to open multiple ports by either using one or multiple clients on the same computer

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things here:

1. Setting the port 'p' for forwarding to be static in transmission-gtk/daemon application which can be done in the config file and saved. This will be maintained across reboots.
2. Creating the port forwarding rule in your router which is more important. This rule states that any network packets coming to your router's external IP at the port p (in point 1), get forwarded correctly to the torrent program listening that port p on your Ubuntu's internal/private IP address (like 192.168.*.*). To do this you would need login/access to the router itself which may not be possible in corporate networks. It is simple in home routers (192.168.*.*/html/index1.html) but many routers don't have persistent memory which can propagate that rule across reboots.

*Does that answer your question, still not completely sure what it is yet.*